# Powershell Change User Password

Tags: powershell

I have a vSphere Win 10 VM called **Win10x64** ,with username **admin** and password **1234**,

And I'm trying to change admin user password with this powercli command:

```
$VMUsername = 'admin'  
$VMName = 'Win10x64'

#Generate random password
$Password = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::Generatepassword(12,0)

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Script = "Set-LocalUser -Name $VMUsername -Password $Password"
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMName -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $Script -GuestUser Admin -GuestPassword '1234'
```

But I Get This Error Every Time Even though I Use Secure String...

```
Set-LocalUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type
|  "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
|  At line:1 char:56
|  + ... r -Name Win 10 X64bit - Liel  -Password System.Security.SecureString}
|  +                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
|      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocalUserCommand
```

How Do Can I Change The **admin** Password?

Thanks.

Comment: No idea how `Invoke-VMScript` works, but can tell you that doing by wrapping your expression in `$Script` with double quotes you're effectively passing the __String__ `System.Security.SecureString` to your script.

Comment: `Invoke-VMScript` doesn't accept parameters, so you can't securely remote the password anyway. Either substitute in the plaintext password (after quoting) or better yet remote *everything*, including the password generation (if you don't actually need the password later -- if you do, consider storing it securely on the VM somewhere and reading it as a file, then deleting). Conceivably you could also do some kind of encryption and decryption, but there's probably not much point to that, since anyone with access to the script probably also has access to any decryption mechanism or key employed.